# Smooth Pareto Plane

Tags: matlab

Let [image]. I want to plot the Pareto surface. The following Matlab code works and produces the attached figure. It's is not very smooth though. Any suggestions how I can get a nice plane?

```
clear all; clc;

fitnessfcn = @(x)[sqrt(x(1)),  sqrt(x(2)),  sqrt(x(3))];

Aeq = [1,1,1];
beq = 1;
lb = [eps,eps,eps];
ub = [1,1,1];

[x,f] = gamultiobj(fitnessfcn,3,[],[],Aeq,beq,lb,ub);

F = scatteredInterpolant(f(:,1),f(:,2),f(:,3),'linear','none');
X = linspace(0,1,100);
[XX,YY] = meshgrid(X,X);
ZZ = F(XX,YY);
mesh(XX,YY,ZZ)
```

[image]

**Solution:** Considering the comments, the following does the job

```
F = fit( [f(:,1), f(:,2)], f(:,3), 'thinplateinterp');
plot(F, [f(:,1), f(:,2)], f(:,3))
zlim([0,1])
```

Comment: To include latex math, go to some online equation editor (e.g. https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) and then link the resulting image.

Comment: Workaround: Define Pareto plane P(u1,u2) = sqrt(1-u1.^2-u2.^2) with u1^2 + u2^2 <=1 and u1,u2 >=0.

Comment: Brute force approach is to just increase the initial population size (E.g. with `options = optimoptions('gamultiobj','PopulationSize',200)`, 50 is default for 3 dimensions). But very suboptimal solution since it will considerably increase the computation time, especially  if you go up to a value where the curve can be considered "smooth".

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad that it helps you, but i'm pretty sure there has to be a better way (because what i suggested is rather poor). One Idea would be to fit a polynomial over the points. That would lead to not exact results, but you could compute a nice looking approximation very fast. Unfortunately I don't have time to look into it.

Comment: The real solution is @LeanderMoesinger, I believe. A non-scientific way of doing it is changing the `scatterinterpolant` method to spline or something similar, but this will only be an aproximation